# warning:incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c, pthreads

hi i am getting the following warning pls help me .

> passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’
>   from incompatible pointer type

my code is:

```
int function(int *);
int main()
{
         pthread_t thread_a;
pthread_create(&thread_a,NULL, function,&connected);
int function(int *fnd)

            {
                int bytes_recieved;;
}
```

Comment: What type is the `connected` argument?

Answer (score 5):

`function` must return a `void *`. See the `pthread_create(3)` man page for more details.

Comment: To return a `void *` from `function`, you can call `pthread_exit(void *)` anywhere in `function` you would normally use `return`.

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html):

`function` must receive and return `void *`.